# Have to eject and reinsert DVD for it to show up in WMP 12 library

Tags: windows-media-player

When I exit Windows Media Player 12 it forgets that I have a DVD in the drive. After restarting WMP I have to eject and reinsert the disk for it to show up in the media library. Is there a way to fix this so that WMP remembers what disks I have in the drive?

Windows 7 x64

Answer (score 0):

Running this Fix it might help:

http://support.microsoft.com/mats/cd_dvd_drive_problems/en-us